# Some cookies not sent to server

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am attempting to set a cookie on a particular page to be read on another page.  I wish to know why the other page is not being sent the cookie.  Examining what is going on shows that the cookie *is* being set, but is not being sent to the server.  My understanding was that if the path of a cookie is not set, the cookie will be sent to any page on the domain, though I tried adding `path=/` to the cookie in case that would help anyhow.  Opera has the cookie tagged as "Only sent to creator" for whatever reason.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
    {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
    }
    setCookie("mycookie",document.location.href,7);
</script>
```

http://www.site.com/Folder/subfolder/page.aspx - Cookie set here

http://www.site.com/folder/page.aspx - Cookie should be sent here.  **Why isn't it?**

Comment: Problem number one: you are testing with Opera!

Comment: @Josh: Actually, I was testing with multiple browsers.  I mentioned Opera because of that setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself, add the path:

```
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString()+" ;path=/");
```

If it's not working, clear all cookies and start again. Old cookies without the path set might be messing something up.

Comment: I typed something wrong when I tried to set the path in hopes of fixing it.  :/

Answer (score 0):

It certainly won't work without explicitly setting `path`; it certainly should work if you are setting the path.